# How to horizontally center fixed content within absolutely positioned parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a modal in my app and it's positioned as fixed within an absolutely positioned container that takes up the whole window.

Something like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="modalWrap">
    <div class="modalContent">
      howdy slick willy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.modalWrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.modalContent {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/513m6kte/3/

It works when the container is set to take up the whole window width (`right: 0`). But, I have a use-case where a chat window may come in from the right, so I'll need the container to not take up the whole width. This is easily accomplished by setting the `right` on the container to `250px`, but the modal content then is no longer centered.

How can i make the modal remain centered within the `.modalWrap` as the width on its container changes?

Comment: why not `postion:absolute` on modal-content? https://jsfiddle.net/ar7mctw2/, sorry if i understood it wrong.

Comment: @AdityaThakur That's a good point, but the issue is that modals can be launched irrespective of the scroll position of the underlying page and I'd like them to remain centered in the viewport even though you might be scrolled halfway down the page. I adjusted the fiddle to show this scenario. I'll probably end up disabling scrolling somehow when a modal is open.

Comment: Hmm... looks like if I make the modal `absolute` and the parent `fixed`, it works how I want.

Comment: ,yes it would a be better idea ,since the content will only be contained by model-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an even easier solution, using flexbox.

Flexbox is relatively new, but is hugely useful - and quite easy. There is a reason why the core change from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4 is moving from aligning with floats to using Flexbox. *In fact, they re-designed the entire Bootstrap grid system - the core of Bootstrap - around flexbox.*

By adding these two lines to the parent div:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

and removing these two lines from the child div (modal content):

```
xxxleft: 50%;
xxxtransform: translateX(-50%);
```

The modal will self-adjust, and always remain centered.

[<kbd>**Updated jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/j90hqmkx/)

---

#### References:

[Excellent, fast-paced 5-min Flexbox Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Best Ever Flexbox Cheat Sheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#justify-content)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ultimate guide for centering that I have used very much: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

This goes through all the options for centering in a Q&A format.